# Python: Extract values from a dictionary and write all values additively to a new list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with varying numbers of elements. e.g.:

```
data = {"Tr1":[1,2,3], "Tr2": [4,5,6], "Tr3": [7,8,9]}
```

I would like to extract all values from the dictionary, and write it to a new separate list. e.g.:

```
outputData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to post the code you've written so far and review [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it with list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for x in data.values() for i in x]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `dict.values()` to get the lists and flatten the result using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain
outputData = list(chain.from_iterable(data.values()))
print(outputData)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```